# C# Search for value inside Array

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I want to search for values inside some arrays, e.g. lets say I have 3 arrays:

```
int[] Year = {1930, 2000, 2020};

string[] Months = {"January", "May", "December"};

int[] NumOfCars = {10, 5, 200};
```

So lets say I want to find how many cars there are in the year 2000, I want to be able to get a result like:

```
RESULT: 2000, May, 5
```

How would I be able to do this. 
Thanks

edited:

I want the user to search for the value without them knowing the values, for e.g. `Console.WriteLine("Search a Year");` and they put the year 2000 and then the program displays the Result.

```
RESULT: 2000, May, 5
```

Answer (score 3):

If your structure is simple, then Kevin's answer is enough.

But if you have more complicated structures you could

```
//Make a model of you data
public class L {
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public string Months {get; set;}
    public int NumOfCars {get; set;}
}

void Main()
{

    List<L> myList = new List<L>();

   //Load you arrays into the structure
    myList.Add(new L { Year = 1930, Months = "January", NumOfCars = 10});
    myList.Add(new L { Year = 2000, Months = "May", NumOfCars = 5});
    myList.Add(new L { Year = 2030, Months = "December", NumOfCars = 30});

    //Use LINQ
    var r = myList.Where(x => x.Year == 2000).Select(x => x);

    Console.Write(r);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. If those arrays are talking about the same thing, creating a class, then mantaining it on a list seems to be the most organized idea.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your arrays and your description, it sounds like you want to find the value in one array and then look up information in the other two based on the position you found in the first.

```
public string LookUpValues(string year)
{

    for(var ii = 0; ii < Year.Length; ii++)
    {
       if(Year[ii] == year)
       {
         return Year[ii] + ", " + Months[ii] + ", " + NumOfCars[ii]

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I do want to find the value in one array and then look up the information but I want the user to search for the value without them knowing the values, for e.g. Console.WriteLine("Search a Year"); and they put the year 2000 and then the program displays the Result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the search with simple linear search as follows

```
using System;
class Find
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] Year = {1930, 2000, 2020};
        string[] Months = {"January", "May", "December"};

        int k;

        int[] NumOfCars = {10, 5, 200};

        Console.Write("enter the year");

        year=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        //Console.Write("search the year");

        for(int i=0;i<Year.Length-1;i++)
        {
            if(year==Year[i])
                k=i;
        }

        Console.Write("Result{0},{1],{2}",Year[k],Months[k],NumOfCars[k]);

   }

}
```